# How to get/suppress french spacing before punctuation in `\href`

Tags: hyperref, babel, french, shorthands

**Attention** I have already a possible answer and will add it soon. I thought it would be useful to have a solution about it on the site. (Other answers are naturally welcome too).

**Question** How to activate or suppress the french spacing before some punctuations like a colon in the text argument of `\href` locally (for one specific `\href`) and globally? Switching the language is not an answer!

Minimal examples for tests (the argument of `\href` should normally be a valid url, so it is a bit unfair to add an example without a colon in the link):

## pdflatex

With pdflatex it depends on the link how the argument of `\href` is printed:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
With pdflatex no french spacing in links with colons: 

\href{link}{a:b}

\href{link:colon}{a:b}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### lualatex

With lualatex the spaces are always there:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
With lualatex always spaces:

\href{link}{a:b}

\href{link:colon}{a:b}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue mentioned by Ulrike Fisher with lualatex can be easily fixed.
This is done in babel-french’s new version (3.3d) which is on the way to CTAN.

The fix is not related to \href; the way babel-french works now is as follows: to decide whether a non-breaking space should be added or not before the colon, the luatex code checks both nodes surrounding the `:’.

1) If a glue (actually width>1sp) is found before the colon, it is removed
and replaced by a non-breaking space (penalty + appropriate glue).

2) If no space precedes the colon, in default mode (AutoSpacePunctuation=true), a non-breaking space is added before the
colon *only if* the next node is *not* a glyph (this is new to v.3.3d).

This way, URLs, MS-DOS paths (C:\Program Files) and timetables (10:55) no longer require {\NoAutoSpacing ...} to be printed correctly. This works for
luatex only, my attempts to do the same using \futurelet failed with xetex
and lead to unreliable results with pdftex.

@jfbu: "the \hskip1sp trick" (\href{link:colon}{a\hskip1sp:b}) is neither
``indicative of some kind of possible bug’’ in babel-french, nor an
alternative to the *documented* \NoAutoSpacing command.

As explained in the documented code of babel-french, this trick is meant for tabular `l’ columns: the following exemple’s output is correct with lualatex (left image) and wrong with xelatex (right image) and pdflatex.

```
\documentclass[french]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Char&Code\\ \hline
.&U+002E\\
:&U+003A\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]   [image]

Unfortunately, the XeTeXinterchar mechanism provides one single class (4095) for all non-characters tokens (glues, kerns, penalties, \hbox, math
boundaries, etc.); this is not sufficient to distinguish between small glues (<=1sp, which should not trigger extra space) and other tokens which do require extra space before French high punctuation characters.

Comment: Thanks that you are trying so hard to improve the situation!

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour of `\href` is different for links with a colon as hyperref does a sort of "link type" recognition. If a colon is found in the link, the text argument is passed through `\hyper@linkurl` which calls `hyper@chars` which deactivates active chars.

The following code shows a number of possibilities. It works with xelatex too. It contains a number of `zzz` in the patches which are only for demo! They show which `\href` are affected by a patch.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman,french]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref,etoolbox,ifluatex}

\begin{document}
\minisec{Default behaviour \ifluatex lualatex \else pdflatex \fi}
\href{link}{a:b}

\href{link:colon}{a:bcolon}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\href{link}{a"=b}

\href{link:colon}{a"=bcolon}    

\selectlanguage{french}

\minisec{Suppress the space locally}

\href{link}{\csname NoAutoSpacing\endcsname a:b}

\href{link:colon}{\csname NoAutoSpacing\endcsname a:bcolon} %not needed with pdflatex

\minisec{Activate the space locally}
(will activate other active characters too)

\href{link}{\csname @safe@activesfalse\endcsname a:b} %not needed, default

\href{link:colon}{\csname @safe@activesfalse\endcsname a:bcolon}%not needed with lualatex

\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\href{link}{\csname @safe@activesfalse\endcsname a"=b} %not needed, default

\href{link:colon}{\csname @safe@activesfalse\endcsname a"=bcolon}

\selectlanguage{french}

\minisec{Suppress the space globally/for a group}
The \texttt{zzz} is only for demo!

\begin{enumerate}
\item With \verb+\NoAutoSpacing+
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\hyper@link@}
   {\expandafter{\Hy@tempb}{#4}}
   {\expandafter{\Hy@tempb}{zzz\csname NoAutoSpacing\endcsname #4}}
   {}{\fail}
\makeatother

\href{link}{a:b}

\href{link:colon}{a:bcolon}


\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\href{link}{a"=b}

\href{link:colon}{a"=bcolon}

\selectlanguage{french}

\endgroup

\item With \verb+\@safe@activestrue+. This will affect other active chars too.
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\hyper@link@}
   {\expandafter{\Hy@tempb}{#4}}
   {\expandafter{\Hy@tempb}{zzz\csname @safe@activestrue\endcsname #4}}
   {}{\fail}
\makeatother

\href{link}{a:b}

\href{link:colon}{a:bcolon}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\href{link}{a"=b}

\href{link:colon}{a"=bcolon}

\selectlanguage{french}


\endgroup

\end{enumerate}

\minisec{Activate the space globally/for a group}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Activate the space by deactivating \verb+\Hy@safe@activestrue+ in 
\verb+\hyper@chars+. This affects only links with colons as can seen by the \texttt{zzz}. It 
affects also other active chars.

\begingroup
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\hyper@chars{%
  \let\#\hyper@hash
  \let\%\@percentchar
  %\Hy@safe@activestrue
  zzz %for demo only!
}

\href{link:colon}{a:bcolon}

\href{link}{a:b}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\href{link}{a"=b}

\href{link:colon}{a"=bcolon}

\selectlanguage{french}

\endgroup

\item Activate the space by patching \verb+\hyper@link@+ and adding \verb+\@safe@activesfalse+.
This affects both types as seen by the \texttt{zzz}. It also affects other active chars.
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\hyper@link@}
   {\expandafter{\Hy@tempb}{#4}}
   {\expandafter{\Hy@tempb}{zzz\csname @safe@activesfalse\endcsname #4}}
   {}{\fail}
\makeatother

\href{link}{a:b}

\href{link:colon}{a:bcolon}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}

\href{link}{a"=b}

\href{link:colon}{a"=bcolon}   

\selectlanguage{french}

\endgroup

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

### Output of pdflatex

[image]

### Output of lualatex

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For one specific `\href`, a solution working with `lualatex` (but not with `xelatex` and `pdflatex`) is

```
\href{link:colon}{a\hskip1sp:b}
\href{linknocolon}{a\hskip1sp:b}
```

That it works is indicative of some kind of possible bug of `frenchb`.

For `pdflatex` one can use `\string:` rather, but in default case where the link itself has a colon, the `\string:` is not needed.

For `xelatex` the mechanism is othe ne of `\XeTeXinterchartokenstate` I don't know simple mark-up to deactivate it (apart from turning if off), but anyhow for the local problem here it is always possible (and this is the `frenchb` documentation recommended method) to use

```
{\NoAutoSpacing\href{link:colon}{a:b}}
```

This works will all engines of course.

For globally turning extra French spaces off in `\href` (works with all engines):

```
\makeatletter
\let\originalhyper@normalise\hyper@normalise
\def\hyper@normalise{\NoAutoSpacing\originalhyper@normalise}
\makeatother
```

Default `\hyper@normalise` starts with a `\begingroup`, but two semi-simple groups are already entered when the added `\NoAutoSpacing` gets executed, so no worries here, its effect will be local to the `\href` execution.

@Ulrike asks about *activating* the French spaces in the `\href` *text*. As seen above this is the case by default with LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX, so I address here the PDFLaTeX case. For this, use

```
\href{http://www.foo.com}{\@safe@activesfalse a:b}
```

Of course this is a bit inconvenient, needs `\makeatletter`, etc..

Again, `hyperref` mechanism to de-activate the Babel shorthands fails for `frenchb` with lualatex/xelatex because `frenchb` does not use active characters *and does not tell Babel to find a way to extend its de-activating mechanism to non-Babel shorthands... which is a bit understandable but causes this issue here that lualatex/xelatex behave differently than pdflatex for  `\href`.* (perhaps `frenchb` should actually declare fake Babel shorthands in lualatex/xelatex case and insert its `\FB@spacingfalse` locally in the `inert` form, but has to be local; not thought much more.)

If one wants to do this globally:

```
\begingroup
\catcode`$ 6
\catcode`# 12
\gdef\href@split $1#$2#$3\\$4{\hyper@@link {$1}{$2}{\@safe@activesfalse$4}\endgroup }
\endgroup
```

---

There is a way to inject a hack into second argument of `\href` and force changed catcode regime of the first argument:

```
\protected\def\myhref#1#2{{%
    % \mymacrochangingcatcodes % for example
    \endlinechar\m@ne\everyeof{{\@safe@activesfalse#2}}%
    \scantokens{\href{#1}}%
}}
```

This way one does not need to hack some internal macro.

- don't do this if spaces are active, (i.e. make space char non active before the `\scantokens`),
- of course, one needs to re-instore all needed catcode changes `href` does for first argument, for example the catcode of `#` or the one of `%`, and for the latter it is not possible, because it is too late, for `\myhref` to have authorized a `%` in first argument,
- the idea here is in case one needs to change more catcodes than those handled by default by `hyperref`, (and `%` must be coded `\%` to start with in link).
- in this example with an extra `\@safe@activesfalse` in second argument the hyperref test for an empty second argument will always take the False branch, but this does not look very important (and applies also to the `\href@split` hacking above)

Such method can be useful when attempting to use `\href` in context with altered catcodes, beyond what `hyperref` has provision for. This is however possibly only distantly relevant to the Question here.

Comment: I don't see why you believe that `a\hskip1sp:b` should work (unless by some side-effect). The code in french.ldf doesn't imply this imho.  I don't think that `\hyper@normalise` is the correct place to patch into hyperref. Code added there will also affect the link, so I wouldn't use if for typesetting effects. Also while *suppressing* the space works it is imho not possible to  *activate* it there.

Comment: what do you mean? it works, that's all. It looks like a bug of `frenchb`. And I indicated `\NoAutoSpacing` as better way. Anyway, the main problem of `frenchb` (or of `babel` or both) is that it finds no way to extend the `\if@safe@actives` babel mechanism to cover its luatex/xetex approaches. `hyperref` uses this mechanism to get active characters such as `:` to behave as if non-active (but they still are). As per issuing `\NoAutoSpacing` in `\hyper@normalise` the link is not affected. All extra spaces from default do not make it to the dvi ps specials or pdf (I trust) although indeed the

Comment: `\space` gets expanded. But one finds in dvi for example `ps:SDict begin [/H /I/Border [0 0 1]BorderArrayPatch/Color [0 1 1]/Action <</Subtype/URI/URI(link:colon)>>/Subtype /Link H.B /ANN pdfmark end` by default. Adding `\NoAutoSpacing` changes nothing.

Comment: `a\hskip1sp:b` does not work with pdflatex  (lualatex is different) and is imho not meant to work. And yes,  `\if@safe@actives` doesn't affect luatex as it doesn't use active chars here. Regarding: `\hyper@normalise`: There are lots of places in the hyperref code where one can inject the `\NoAutoSpacing` without doing harm. But that doesn't mean that every place is good. E.g. assume that you don't want to change : so that it suppress the space, but print another glyph instead. How would you do this in `\hyper@normalise`?

Comment: If you want to affect only the text you have to go via the patching of `\href@split` as indicated at bottom of my edited answer 
(I mean by this that `\href@split` is the earliest opportunity and it is the place to inject arbitrary code into the second argument of `\href`) . But patching `\href@split` will imply the hyperref test for empty hyperlink text will fail. Hence `\hyper@link@` from your answer perhaps better. However I don't understand, why did you ask this question if you had already decided on which macro to patch?

Comment: `\href@split` could be a better place to patch then `\hyper@link@` as it will affect only \href. I will have to check.  I don't quite understand why you blame babel (or frenchb) that hyperref doesn't have more hooks where language files could add something.

Comment: Patching `\href@split` takes few lines without package, patching `\hyper@link@` is cumbersome without package.

Comment: Did you read the first two lines of the question?

Comment: `hyperref` is as it is and is such a core package one has to take it as it is. `frenchb` has evolved by changing methods over the years, and when it stopped using active characters for luatex/xetex it did not make effort to prevent the corresponding breaking changes.

Comment: hyperref can evolve too. And one reason for my question was a feature request for hyperref (https://github.com/ho-tex/hyperref/issues/36) which started me thinking.

Comment: Which makes me wonder if Babel should provide some mechanism for this.