# Babel's automatic spacing seems to disappear in \href when the target is an URL

Tags: hyperref, babel, links, french, babel-french

Babel provides automatic spacing around some characters for French, but `hyperref`'s `\href` command seems to mess that up in certain particular contexts. See this example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

a: b; c?

\href{target}{a: b; c?}

\href{http://a.b}{a: b; c?}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Interestingly enough, the problem does not seem to occur when the target is not an URL, but that does not help me much…

Any idea how to prevent this? Adding `\,` and `~` manually in each link is rather annoying. Thanks!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394208/how-to-get-suppress-french-spacing-before-punctuation-in-href/394238#394238

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for the link! I'm surprised this did not show up as a suggestion when I typed the question though… I hope all this stuff about patching `hyperref`'s commands won't have side effects: I guess they had their reason to deactivate active characters in the first place.